# Deploy VS2012 SharePoint 2010 Two Projects in Solution - Cannot see 2nd Feature in SharePoint

Tags: feature, debugging

This is probably going to sound vague, but I have two C# SharePoint projects within a solution.

I have been working on Project 1 for a while and it gets deployed to my local instance of SharePoint on my development machine.

Project 1 consists of 1 Package, 1 Feature, 1 Module and a number of Application Pages.

I started work on Project 2 yesterday.  It consists of 1 Package, 1 Feature, 1 Module and a number of Application Pages.

I set Project 2 to my default project in the solution and start debugging.  I cannot see my feature in the Site Settings->Manage site features.

Both were created from the SharePoint 2010 Project template.  I am unsure on how to diagnose this one.

The configuration between Project 1 and 2 in terms of Package/Feature/Module looks fine.

In a nutshell, Project 2 has:

**Project Properties**

Active Deployment Configuration - No Activation (this does not make a difference when set to Default)

Sandboxed Solution - False

Site URL - http//mydesktoppc/

**Package**

- Layouts
- SSFDM Feature
- Project Items contains SSFDM (Module)

**Package Properties**

Deployment Server Type - WebFrontEnd

Description - some text

Name - e.g. Company.Project2.SSFDM

Solution Id - 13e01bbe-b033-4d8f-a2d8-4cdc76ff9304

Title - SSFDM

**Feature**

- Contains SSFDM (Module)

**Feature Properties**

Activate On Default - False

Always Force Install - True

Creator - ME!

Deployment Path - $SharePoint.Project.FileNameWithoutExtension$_$SharePoint.Feature.FileNameWithoutExtension$

Description - some text

Feature Id - 53af07c8-79c6-49a9-9ee1-99dcdf3eca43

Scope - Site

Title - SSFDM Feature

**Module**

Elements.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Module Name="SSFDM"
                    Url="SitePages"
          Path="SSFDM">
    <File Name="XX1.aspx"
                    Url="DataEntry/XX1.aspx"
                    Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
    <File Name="XX2.aspx"
                    Url="DataEntry/XX2.aspx"
                    Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
    <File Name="XX3.aspx"
                    Url="DataEntry/XX3.aspx"
                    Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
    <File Name="Default.aspx"
                    Url="Default.aspx"
                    Type="GhostableInLibrary" />
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

**UPDATE**

The solution is now showing up under Farm Solutions, but I cannot see the Feature SSFDM in the site features.  The SharePoint 2010 Administration Service was not running initially.

Comment: Does your Project2 solution appear in the solution gallery when debugging? Is it activated?

Comment: Hi James...  Good point.  I have just checked this.  When I go into solutions the following is showing up:  "Your resource quota is 300 server resources. Solutions can consume resources and may be temporarily disabled if your resource usage exceeds your quota."

Comment: But there is no solutions listed.

Comment: Ive checked for Project 1 and this does not show in here either (My Root Site Collection Name : Solution Gallery : Solutions

Comment: That'll be why the Feature isn't listed, it's not deployed. Try a deploy without debugging and see what happens then.

Comment: Project 1 appears under http://mydesktoppc:7262/_admin/Solutions.aspx but Project 2 does not.

Comment: BTW Project 1 did not appear in My Root Site Collection Name : Solution Gallery : Solutions

Comment: The solution gallery is used for Sandbox Solutions. Since you have the LAYOUTS directory in your solution, I'm assuming you are deploying a Farm solution, which will only appear in Central Admin.

Comment: OK.  I tried a deploy and it turned out the SharePoint 2010 Administration service was not running.  I started this and the solution now appears in the Farm Solutions.  It still did not show in the Site Features.  I retracted then removed the solution.  When I debug Project 2 it nows shows in the Farm Solutions.

Comment: OK, this is not a Sandboxed solution - it is a Farm Solution.  I am deploying SSFDM as a Site scoped feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Feature Solution Id was missing at the time of posting this problem.  I have not corrected this by adding the Solution Id as defined in the package.  Putting this in then trying did not show the feature.  However the other Feature Properties have the following:

Scope - Web

Solution Id - 13e01bbe-b033-4d8f-a2d8-4cdc76ff9304

Version - 1.0.0.0

The solution Id was the main culprit for this issue.